# WAMP Sendmail hacked

Tags: php, wamp, sendmail

I have to replace someone and take over the admin of a WAMP server, so I'm quite new to this, sorry if information is missing.
There is an old Joomla running on it, and site has been hacked a few days ago. I updated stuff and now everything is fine.
But I realised Apache error logs were growing fast. It contains lost of :
sendmail: Error during delivery: Spam detected.

Looking at the Sendmail debug.log, I can see SPAM being sent using my server (end of this post)

How can I find out where it is originated from and block that ?

> 16/11/24 10:22:27 ** --- MESSAGE BEGIN --- 16/11/24 10:22:27 ** To:
>   rwiddersjr@comcast.net 16/11/24 10:22:27 ** Subject: We do have a
>   search for a partner 16/11/24 10:22:27 ** Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016
>   10:22:27 +0100 16/11/24 10:22:27 ** From: Crystal
>    16/11/24 10:22:27 ** Message-ID:
>   <8ee993a214679b255898182e1b476590@intranet.cohl.fr> 16/11/24 10:22:27
>   ** X-Priority: 3 16/11/24 10:22:27 ** MIME-Version: 1.0 16/11/24 10:22:27 ** Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 16/11/24 10:22:27 **
>   boundary="b1_8ee993a214679b255898182e1b476590" 16/11/24 10:22:27 **
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 16/11/24 10:22:27 ** 16/11/24 10:22:27
>   ** 16/11/24 10:22:27 ** --b1_8ee993a214679b255898182e1b476590 16/11/24 10:22:27 ** Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii 16/11/24
>   10:22:27 ** [...] Connecting to smtp.completel.fr:25 16/11/24 10:22:27
>   ** Connected. 16/11/24 10:22:27 << 220 smtp3.mail.completel.net ESMTP Postfix 16/11/24 10:22:27 >> EHLO SRVWEB01.****** 16/11/24
>   10:22:27 <<
>   250-smtp3.mail.completel.net250-PIPELINING250-SIZE
>   51200000250-ETRN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250
>   DSN 16/11/24 10:22:27 >> MAIL FROM:
>    16/11/24 10:22:27 << 250 2.1.0 Ok
>   16/11/24 10:22:27 >> RCPT TO:  16/11/24
>   10:22:28 << 250 2.1.5 Ok 16/11/24 10:22:28 >> DATA 16/11/24
>   10:22:28 << 354 End data with .

Comment: Do you need to use mail? One option is to disable it. Otherwise you need to find the files causing it. Look for things like `eval(base64decode('fniun32yuqb4u32bu));`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried and disabled it in php.ini and it works. The problem is I need to send emails to warn people that someone else has modified a DB.  I am currently looking for eval(base64decode chain, what is the purpose of that command ? Thanks

Comment: You can try using https://www.sparkpost.com/ to post mail instead. It just uses a curl to send the email content to them. You can get 100k emails a month free

Comment: base64decode will decode base64 encoded text to executable php. then eval will run it. it's a way to hide code.

Comment: Thanks again. My provider is blocking the email as SPAM anyway, so that is not a big issue here. But I couldn't find any file containing eval(base64decode  (research made with notepad++, windows search being really bad)